# Update parent version and artefactId

Tags: maven, maven-plugin

I want to dynamically update my parent version and artefactId.

Let's say I have the following `pom.xml`

```
<parent>
    <groupId>com.company</groupId>
    <artifactId>my-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
</parent>

<artifactId>my-child</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
```

Is there any possibility to update (set) parent artefactId/version.

I.e. I can set a child version via `versions` plugin

`mvn org.codehaus.mojo:versions-maven-plugin:2.7:set -DnewVersion=1.2.3-SNAPSHOT`

Is there something like it for parent updating?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `versions:update-parent` to update your parent pom to the latest version. I never heard of a plugin to change the artifactId.

I would be interested to know why more than parent pom is required.